# Parse input file from user with a specific library, R shiny

Tags: shiny

I have been trying to parse a user input file with a specific library in `server.R` script. But there is something wrong with script which I can't understand properly. I hope someone would help me solving this issue.

Following are the `ui.R` & `server.R` scripts

**`ui.R`**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
        titlePanel("MA analysis app - testing"),

        sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(helpText("This version only receives samples files"),

                fileInput('file1', label="Upload samples files:", accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-value', 'text/palin', '.csv', '.txt')),

        tags$hr(),

        checkboxInput('header', label='Header', FALSE)),

        mainPanel(plotOutput("plotMDS"))

)

))
```

**`server.R`**

```
    library(shiny)
    library(limma)
    library(illuminaHumanv4.db)

    options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)

    shinyServer(function(input, output){

            Dat=reactive({
                    inFile=input$file1
                    if(is.null(inFile))
                    return(NULL)
                    dat=read.ilmn(inFile, other.columns="Detection")

            })

            output$plotMDS=renderPlot({
                    plotMDS(Dat()$dat$E)

    })

    })
```

And the error is: **`Error:'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'`** I can see the error without even uploading the file.

A general R script to do above task would be following

```
library(limma)
library(illuminaHumanv4.db)

dat=read.ilmn("samples.txt", other.columns="Detection")
plotMDS(dat$E)

class(dat)
[1] "EListRaw"
attr(,"package")
[1] "limma"
```

I could write a script where server script receives the files from default locations and its working but I would like to enable the user input option. I would be grateful if someone shares their views.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I understand correct, I should replace `input$file1` with `input$datapath`? I would appreciate if you could explain in little more.

Comment: No it's `input$file1$datapath`. Sorry for the confusion. I meant to type `inFile1` but got it wrong.

Comment: I've changed and tried to run the app. But it doesn't show any plot. Instead I see these at R console `Warning: Error in array: 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'`. Does this line `server.R` script correct? `plotMDS(Dat()$dat$E)`

Comment: I think it's `plotMDS(Dat()$E)`. Also in the last line of the reactive, either remove `dat=`, or add `dat` as a new line (so that the reactive returns the dat object)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've made few changes as you suggested. Its working fine.